# pdf.js not working on Android native browser

Tags: android, pdf.js

Viewer (http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) not working on Android native browser (i tested it on 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 devices). PDF-file is loaded (progress bar show progress), but not displayed.

If pdf file has no image, it works fine, but if has some images, it shows "loading " and blank pages (some pdfs with images works just fine).